# не устанавливается socket.io

Tags: node.js

Всем привет помогите с ошибкой! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/node-js-ubuntu-14-04-ru 
делал тут всё по инструкции и при утановке socket.io ( npm install socket.io )

```css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: socket.io
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /root/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-63-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: socket.io
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```